# come out in favour

Tags: sentence-meaning

Learning the meaning of come out, I came across the following sentence in a dictionary:

> In her speech, the senator came out in favour of a change in the law.

The meaning of come out in the sentence should be to say publicly whether you agree or disagree with something. But inspite of the mentioning it, I didn;t understand that sentence. Couldn't you explain it in other words?

UPD: I understand the sentence in general, but it's not clear to me whether the senator was agree or disagree with her.

Comment: Note that in the sentence, *the senator* is *her*.

Comment: As @DamkerngT. says, the speech was made by the senator, and in it she expressed agreement with the proposition that the law should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a definition of *come out* in another dictionary, Macmillan Dictionary:

> **[come out](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/come-out#come-out__12)**
>   10 ​ to state a decision or opinion officially or publicly
>   ​　　**come out in favor of/against (doing) something:** *The commission has come out against the takeover.*

In your example,

> In her speech, the senator came out in favour of a change in the law.

the meaning of *come out* is, as you said, "to say publicly whether you agree or disagree with something". In this case the senator, who is female and we know that because of *her* in *In her speech*, stated her agreement (because it's *in favour of*) on a change in the law. She did so either officially or publicly or perhaps both. Maybe she gave her speech to the House (or both Houses) or the Parliament. (Maybe the latter, considering the spelling of *favour*.)